# How do I play an MP3 or WAV through the computer's internal speaker?

Tags: hardware, sound, notification

I'd like to have a script play a pretty chime sound as a notification, but I want it to use the internal speaker because the external sound system isn't always powered on.

Beeping is not an option; it makes passers-by think there is something wrong.

Comment: An alternative to this is possibly supplying speakers - this depends on your hardware though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The internal speaker typically cannot do anything but beep. It's not usually connected to any sound hardware.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_speaker